# Contentful SDK, extending generic object Typescript type

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, contentful

I am writing an app using the Contentful App SDK, but I'm running into an issue with Typescript typings. I'm passing a parameter to a dialog like so:

```
sdk.dialogs.openCurrentApp({title: "Edit Layout", parameters:{id}});
```

But when I try to access the property in the dialog component I find that when I try to access the attribute under "invocations" as described in the documentation, I get an error: "Property 'id' does not exist on type 'Object'."

```
const layoutId = sdk.parameters?.invocation?.id;
```

I tried using `hasOwnProperty` to check that the object indeed contains `id` to harden my code, but it does not help with the Typescript typing error:

```
const layoutId = sdk.parameters?.invocation?.hasOwnProperty("id") && sdk.parameters.invocation.id;
```

I had a quick look [in the source of the SDK](https://ahttps://github.com/contentful/ui-extensions-sdk/blob/3623120460c2d7f4feb6aa52e4babf03c51e025d/lib/types.ts#L610) and found that the Parameter indeed uses a generic object type.

I tried making a custom type with id added and casting to that, but that does not quite work:

```
type ParameterInvocationWithId = {
  id: string;
} & ParametersAPI;

...

const layoutId = sdk.parameters?.invocation?.hasOwnProperty("id") && sdk.parameters.invocation.id as ParameterInvocationWithId;
```

What would be the best way to deal with this?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I needed to specify a type to show the shape of the object on `invocation`:

```
interface InvocationParams {
  id?: string;
}
```

Then, instead of using `hasOwnProperty` or trying to access id directly I had to do it in two steps, so I would create a new const from the invocation object and cast it to my params type and then pluck the id off that object:

```
const params = sdk.dialog.parameters?.invocation as InvocationParams;
let layoutId = params.id;
```

Comment: or using string accessor? like `sdk.dialog.parameters?.invocation['id']`?

Comment: Tried that. Did not work either: `Property 'id' does not exist on type 'Object'.`